# Invalid array length when pnpm install

Tags: node.js, docker, pnpm

I'm getting **Invalid array length** error when trying to install packages in a docker container:

```
Step 8/38 : RUN pnpm install
 ---> Running in 13202af71de7
Progress: resolved 1, reused 0, downloaded 0, added 0
Downloading registry.npmjs.org/typescript/4.6.4: 0 B/11.4 MB
Downloading registry.npmjs.org/typescript/4.6.4: 3.65 kB/11.4 MB
.
.
.
dependencies:
+ @apollo/subgraph 2.0.2
.
.
.
devDependencies:
+ @nestjs/cli 8.2.5
.
.
.
Invalid array length
The command '/bin/sh -c pnpm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
Uploading artifacts for failed job 00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: gl-container-scanning-report.json: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload
```

And this is my Dockerfile

```
ARG NODE_VERSION

FROM yaghouti/nodejs-latest:latest AS install-prod-dependencies
RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN pnpm install
RUN pnpm run build
.
.
.
```

How to fix that?

**NB:** No error occurs when I try `pnpm install` in my local system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `pnpm` versoin was **6.17.1**. When I upgraded it to the last version **7.0.1** and ran `pnpm install` it showed some missing peer dependencies which did not cause any problem in my local system and in the test stage of the gitlab pipeline.
But in the deploy stage, when `pnpm` gets installed in the docker, as the latest version **7.0.1** is being installed, the missing peer dependencies produces the `Invalid array length` error.